# Centre Lottie SVG to a Header element

Tags: javascript, html, css, pug, lottie

I have an animation from Lottiefiles (in JSON format), which is then converted into an animated SVG document by the Lottie framwork. However, I can't seem to position the SVG document with the header tag. I'd like it to be beside the text.

I tried to search existing threads for similar things, but none of these worked, except for one (sort of). This included adding the SVG into a div, inside the header itself. However, when I tried this, the SVG document is fixed in place, so while it worked for shorter text (less than 6 characters), if the text was longer, the SVG would appear underneath, instead of moving to the end of the text.

I also have to manually assign the style to the SVG file through Javascript in a timeout, because the SVG document doesn't exist initially.

This is the actual header code (in PugJS).

```
 h1(class="channel-header" style="margin-bottom: 36px; width: 96px; margin: auto;") #{channel}
            if premium
                div(id="bodyanim" class="badge baseline")
```

Here is the SASS for the header and inner div tag:

```
.badge
  display: inline-flex
  align-self: center
  height: 70%

.badge svg, .badge img
  height: 1em
  width: 1em
  fill: currentColor
  z-index: -1
  position: absolute
  left: 0
  top: 0


.badge.baseline svg, .badge img
  top: .125em
  position: relative

.channel-header
  margin: 0 0 16px 0
  padding: 0
  line-height: 1
  font-weight: normal
  position: relative
  height: 45px
```

And here's the JS setting the SVG object, and setting its CSS after a timeout.

```
var animData = {
    wrapper: document.getElementById('bodyanim'),
    animType: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    prerender: true,
    autoplay: true,
    path: '/anims/4768-trophy.json'
};

var anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);

setTimeout(function () {
    var svg = animData.wrapper.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    svg.style.position = "absolute";
    svg.style.left = "0";
    svg.style.top = "0";
    svg.style.zIndex = -1;
    svg.style.marginLeft = "65%";

}, 100);
```

When I run the site with this code, the header works for any text shorter than 7 characters, but if there's more, the header tries to "push" itself above the SVG document, and the SVG remains in position behind it instead of moving along with the text.
You can see an example of this on this site (you can either edit the endpoint, i.e. */channel/anythinghere* or edit the tag client-side):

http://themadgamers.co.uk:3000/channel/ItsMike

Comment: Include a working example using generated source to clearly outline the problem.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Sorry about that, I edited the question to include links to screenshots of both working and not working.

Comment: The issue is that there's no easy way for us to test this. It's just a bunch of code on a screen. A link to a working example would be great so I can test out possible solutions. Try [CodeSandbox](http://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: Better yet, edit your question to include the compiled html/css as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (Also, I don't think `div` elements are permitted within `h1` elements—you might want to use a `header` instead of an `h1`)

Comment: @AndyHoffman Ah sorry that makes more sense. I couldn't get CodeSandbox to work with the required JS files, but I've thrown it onto a server of mine where you can see it live.

Comment: @sean Thanks that's good to know, I've edited it to use header instead, and added a live version

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set a fixed width for your `h1`?

```
 h1(class="channel-header" style="margin-bottom: 36px; width: 96px; margin: auto;")
```

If you remove the `96px` width restriction, longer strings no longer push the trophy below the user names.

[image]

As for the manual need to style the `SVG` via `JavaScript`...

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var svg = animData.wrapper.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
  svg.style.position = "absolute";
  svg.style.left = "0";
  svg.style.top = "0";
  svg.style.zIndex = -1;
  svg.style.marginLeft = "65%";
}, 100);
```

Consider adding a new `class` to your `CSS`.

```css
.mySvg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 65%;
}
```

Then you should be able to simplify the `JavaScript` to:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var svg = animData.wrapper.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
  svg.className = "mySvg";
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I removed the width on the header, but the trophy disappears, presumably off-screen somewhere. If I remove or change `margin-left` it reappears but will still be behind the text. Was there something with the `position` tag that you changed?

Comment: Edit: I figured out that the `width` was automatically being set to 100% by the Lottie framework, which was pushing the header to the side. The only problem now is that the JavaScript setting the className doesn't seem to work, which i'm assuming is again due to Lottie overriding it, since no errors are thrown. It seems as long as I override the `width` it'll be fine